# ¿Cómo encontrar una palabra específica en una cadena de texto en javascript o jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Intento encontrar una palabra específica en una cadena de texto la cual obtengo al capturar el nombre de un archivo que cargo en una etiqueta de tipo file (`type="file`) para realizar una condicion la cual me marque como seleccionado un select si el nombre del archivo lleva alguno de los valores que este tiene:

```js
$('#archivoFRR').change(function(){
  var file = $(this).val();
  console.log(file);
  // aqui deberia de ir el condicional donde compare la cadena de texto (el nombre del archivo) con
  // la palabra que deseo en este caso seria "1" es decir si encuentro "1"
  // en el nombre del archivo este me seleccionara la opcion que tenga como valor "1"
  if('' == '1'){
    $("select option[value='1']").attr("selected","selected");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="file" id="archivoFRR"  name="archivoFRR" >
<br>
<br>
<select id="select" name="select" >
   <option value="1">Facturación</option>
   <option value="2">Recaudo</option>
   <option value="3">ReFacturación</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Tu dices que si el archivo se llama: "nombre1" o "nomb_1" entonces busca el "1" y como coincide ya haces tu selected... a esto te refieres?, pero el nombre del archivo lo tienes en: "file"????

Comment: si, los usuarios de la aplicación que estoy desarrollando siempre suben archivos con un nombre en especifico digamos, por ejemplo (**txt_1**) , entonces deseo buscar en el nombre del archivo y si encuentra  una palabra en especial _en este caso **1**_ me seleccione una opción

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Revisa esta código, esta comentado, si no te funciona algo estoy para servirte.

```js
$('#archivoFRR').change(function(){
  var file = $(this).val();
  (file && file.search(/1/g) > 0 ? $("select option[value='1']").attr("selected","selected"):$("select option[value='0']").attr("selected","selected")); 
  /*Te explico:
    para buscar el numero 1 solo debes usar la función search que viene integrada nativamente en los string, para hacer una busqueda debes agregar las barras invertidas /txtBuscar/ y despues agregar la: g para decirle que lo haga de forma global. Ahora la función search te devuelve la posición donde encontro el texto que buscas, por eso le indico que sea mayor que 0
  */
 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="file" id="archivoFRR"  name="archivoFRR" >
<br>
<br>
<select id="select" name="select" >
   <option value="0">--Elige opcion--</option>
   <option value="1">Facturación</option>
   <option value="2">Recaudo</option>
   <option value="3">ReFacturación</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Me funciono perfecto, lo único fue que como uso palabras tuve que colocar todo en minúsculas pero ya, muchas gracias